# Symfony - failed to open stream only in Command

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 4.
In my code, I have a function I use in a Controller and in a Command.

```
public function offlinequiz_check_scanned_page($scannedpage, $colle) {
    ....
    $this->load_stored_image($scannedpage->getFilename(), $scannedpage, $colle);
    ....
}

public function load_stored_image($file, $scannedpage, $colle) {
    ....

    $pathparts = pathinfo($file);
    $filename = $pathparts['filename'] . '.' . $pathparts['extension'];
    $imageinfo = getimagesize($file);
    ....
}
```

When used in the controller, the function works just fine.
In the Command, I have this error :

```
Failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

`$scannedpage` is the same object in both cases.

`getFilename()` returns an image path : `./uploads/copies/xxx/image_name.jpg`.

The upload directory is in `/public`.

I tried to use Asset Component to get the right path but theses images are uploaded by users and are not managed by Webpack Encore so when I try this :

```
$package = new Package(new EmptyVersionStrategy());
$this->load_stored_image($package->getUrl($scannedpage->getFilename()), $scannedpage, $colle);
```

It returns the same as : `$scannedpage->getFilename()`.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the command from `/public` directory?

Comment: The Command is in `App/Command` and is ran with `php bin/console ...`. I think it's the issue but I don't know how to solve it. I tried to find a way to always get the right path in the `offlinequiz_check_scanned_page` function whether it's called from a Command or a Controller but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: `./uploads/copies/xxx/image_name.jpg` This path is relative to `/public` directory. You should consider making this path absolute, You can prepend the absolute path of `/public` folder to the result of `getFilename()`

Comment: If I'm correct, if I do that, it will return an error in the Controller. And how would I get this image in twig ? As of now, I was getting it with `<img src="{{ asset(copie.filename|raw) }}">`